# Postgres 9.4 which type of index would be ideal for a float column

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.4

I was in mysql and now have joined postgres and I have a table that is getting up to 300,000 new records a day but also has many reads. I have 2 columns that I think would be ideal for indexes: latitudes and longitudes and I Know that postgres has different types of indexes and my question is which type of index would be best for a table that has many writes and reads? This is the query for the reads

```
SELECT p.fullname,s.post,to_char(s.created_on, 'MON DD,YYYY'),last_reply,s.id,
r.my_id,s.comments,s.city,s.state,p.reputation,s.profile_id 
FROM profiles as p INNER JOIN streams as s ON (s.profile_id=p.id) Left JOIN 
reputation as r ON (r.stream_id=s.id and r.my_id=?) where s.latitudes >=? 
AND ?>= s.latitudes AND s.longitudes>=? AND ?>=s.longitudes order by 
s.last_reply desc limit ?"
```

As you can see the 2 columns in the where clause are latitudes and longitudes

Comment: If you're doing a spatial match to check if a point belongs to a region - then your query is not correct. Being "between" of both dimensions is not a sufficient criteria.

Comment: You are correct thanks for pointing that out, just learned something new.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PostgreSQL has the [`point` data type](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-geometric.html#AEN6730) with many [operators](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-geometry.html) that have good support from the [`gist` index](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/gist-builtin-opclasses.html). So if at all possible change your table definition to use a `point` rather than 2 `float`s.

Inserting `point` data is very easy, just use `point(longitudes, latitudes)` for the column, instead of putting the two values in separate columns. Same with getting data out: `lnglat[0]` is the longitude and `lnglat[1]` is the latitude.

The index would be something like this:

```
CREATE INDEX idx_mytable_lnglat ON streams USING gist (lnglat pointops);
```

There is also the [`box` data type](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-geometric.html#AEN6814), which would be great for grouping all your parameters and finding a point in a box is highly optimized in the `gist` index.

With a `point` in the table and a `box` to search on, your query reduces to this:

```
SELECT p.fullname, s.post, to_char(s.created_on, 'MON DD,YYYY'), last_reply, s.id,
       r.my_id, s.comments, s.city, s.state, p.reputation, s.profile_id 
FROM profiles AS p
JOIN streams AS s ON (s.profile_id = p.id)
LEFT JOIN reputation AS r ON r.stream_id = s.id AND r.my_id = ?
WHERE s.lnglat && box(?, ?, ?, ?)
ORDER BY s.last_reply DESC
LIMIT ?;
```

The phrase `s.lnglat && box(?, ?, ?, ?)` means "the value of column lnglat overlaps with (meaning: is inside) the box".

Comment: Thanks a lot @patrick that was very helpful will change it to a point and then index it gist. That should definately speed up reads.

Answer (score 2):

If the latitude or longitude columns are sorted, you would probably want to use a B-tree index.

From the Postgres documentation page on indices:

> B-trees can handle equality and range queries on data that can be sorted into some ordering. In particular, the PostgreSQL query planner will consider using a B-tree index whenever an indexed column is involved in a comparison using one of the [greater than / lesser than-type operators]

You can read more about indices [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/indexes-types.html).

Edit: Some of the G* indices look like they might be of use if you need to index on both latitude and longitude, since they appear to allow multi-dimensional  (e.g. 2d) indexing.

Edit2: In order to actually create the index, you'd want to do something along the lines of (although you may need to change the table name to suite your needs):

```
CREATE INDEX idx_lat ON s(latitudes);
```

Take note that B-tree indices are default so you don't need to specify the type.

Read more about index creation [here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/sql-createindex.html).

Comment: It would be even more helpful if you suggested what indexes OP might created.